# Atualizar Role do usuário ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

olá pessoal eu estou encontrando dificuldades en atualizar a role do usuario ao atualizar meus dados, minhas roles estão sendo preenchidas atravez de uma ViewBag no meu get da minha controller e estou recuperando o novo ID no post de minha controller atraves do request.form segue o codigo do meu poste.

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UserEdit(ApplicationUser appuser)
    {

        var context = new Models.ApplicationDbContext();
        var user = context.Users.Where(u => u.Id == appuser.Id).FirstOrDefault();
        user.LockoutEnabled = appuser.LockoutEnabled;

        //Recupera o ID do novo item
        var newRole = Request.Form["RoleId"].ToString();

        //Aqui eu deveria a atualização da role


        context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("UserList");
    }
```

obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então questão resolvida da seguinte forma

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AccessDeniedAuthorizeAttribute(Roles = "Administrador")]
    public ActionResult UserEdit(ApplicationUser appuser)
    {
        var context = new Models.ApplicationDbContext();
        var user = context.Users.Where(u => u.Id == appuser.Id).FirstOrDefault();
        user.LockoutEnabled = appuser.LockoutEnabled;

        //Recupera o ID da nova Role onde esse e um Dropdownlist na minha view
        int newRole = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["RoleId"].ToString());
        var role = context.Roles.Where(u => u.Id == newRole.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
        var oldRoleId = user.Roles.SingleOrDefault().RoleId;
        var oldRoleName = context.Roles.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Id == oldRoleId).Name;

        //Aqui eu atualizo a minha role
        UserManager.RemoveFromRole(user.Id, oldRoleName);
        UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, role.Name);

        context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("UserList");
    }
```

Obrigado a todos.